# How i can resize my browser without break the long values on the navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive

Just that, I got a navbar with 3 short values and a long one,

```
<div id="navegation" class="col-12 col-m-12">
    <ul class="none col-12-block col-m-12-block">
            <a href="#" class="col-3"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"/></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="navOption col-2">Navbar 1</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="navOption col-2 col-m-2">Navbar 2</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="navOption col-2">Navbar 3</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="navOption col-2">Navbar Long Name 1</li></a>
    </ul>
```

When i resize the browser window my "Navbar Long Name 1" gets a break row and escape from the div or the div gets resized and unpositioned. 
I tryed using:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 660px) {
 .navOption{ content:"short stuff" }}
```

But it seems like the content must be empty to get rewrited.

Now im thinking about use the tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to capture the screen width somehow with jquery or js and set a conditional with an `.innerHtml` or `.val()`. But maybe im overthinking and there is a css way to respect the content with `overflow:auto;` or something like that.

Maybe you can help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: What css framework are you using for the col classes?

Comment: insert in head <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: @Manish what difference does it will make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some media queries with helper classes to allow you to switch the content

.desktop-only and .mobile-only are used below.

See http://codepen.io/dmoojunk/pen/LNerPm

```css
@media only screen and (min-width:992px) {
  .desktop-only {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .mobile-only {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .mobile-only {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .desktop-only {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="desktop-only">Navbar Long Name 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="mobile-only">Navbar Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap to do it :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul class="row">
            <a href="#"><img class="col-xs-2 logo" src="img/logo.png"/></a>
            <a href="#" class=" col-xs-2"><li class="navOption">Navbar 1</li></a>
            <a href="#" class=" col-xs-2"><li class="navOption">Navbar 2</li></a>
            <a href="#" class=" col-xs-2"><li class="navOption">Navbar 3</li></a>
            <a href="#" class=" col-xs-4"><li class="navOption">Navbar Long Name 1</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but the problem persist, as you can see in the snipplet when you resize to the shortest width "NavbarLongName1" got broken row, and in my case the names are specialy long, so i will need to edit the content to place an abreviature. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spaces use  
eg.
`Navbar&nbsp;Long&nbsp;Name&nbsp;1`

Comment: does '&nbsp' prevent the browser from breakrow it?

Comment: Yes it does, if display is inline-block